# Wagtail route still returns 404

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I encountered a bit weird problem and not really sure why it happens.

This is my model:

```
class PostIndexPage(RoutablePage):
    max_count = 1
    parent_page_types = []
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full")
    ]

    @route(r'^posts/$')
    def main(self, request):
        from django.shortcuts import render
        return render(request, self.get_template(request), self.get_context(request))
```

I defined route in that model but it seems to have no effect.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-index-page/ - the old url is still working the old way
http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/ - but this one doesn't (404, not found).

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

URL routes defined by `@route` on a RoutablePage are relative to the normal path of the page, as determined by its slug and position in the page tree. If you created a routable page with the slug `post-index-page`, the `posts` route will be found at `/post-index-page/posts/`.

If you want a view that remains at a completely fixed URL, you can always define that as a standard Django view.

Comment: > If you want a view that remains at a completely fixed URL, you can always define that as a standard Django view.

How do you set up a wagtail page at a fixed URL? The options I see are
a) create pages above it and set all the slugs up to make the desired path
b) create a second wagtail root which it sees as a different site which doesn't _sound_ like what's intended

Comment: @jbothma You can set up a Django view at the fixed URL, that retrieves your chosen page and returns the result of calling `.serve(request)` on it. But if you're doing that in conjunction with RoutablePageMixin as in this example, then there's basically no Wagtail left at all - you're just writing plain Django (with, at most, a `FooPage.objects.get(slug='something')` line so that you can pull data from a page).